# Laravel 5.4 Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value with fix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Using Optional Parameters

When i use optional parameters in Laravel 5.4, i get the error internal error: failed to retrieve the default value.
Here is My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:SUPER_ADMIN'],'prefix' => 'SWSM-Dashboard'], function () {


Route::get('/', 'HomeController@eventDashboard');

Route::group(['prefix' => '/providers'],function (){

    Route::get('create/{providerData?}','ProvidersController@create');
    Route::get('delete/{providerId?}','ProvidersController@destroy');
    Route::get('/','ProvidersController@index');


    }); 
});
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function create($providerData){ dd('Hello'); }
```

My middleware is just the standard Auth out of the box with Laravel so i'm surprised that this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I am using php 5.3 so type hinting is not available to me, so i would not normally use it.

The problem is resolved by doing the following to the optional parameter you want to use inside your controller.

```
  public function create($providersData = null)
  {

    dd($providersData);

  }
```

Now when the route is hit with ..../create/ it will die and dump null but when the route is hit with ..../create/1 the providersData parameter will be set to 1 and die and dump.